# Firefox/palemoon random moments of not responding

Tags: firefox, freeze

I have Firefox 5.0.1 installed on Windows 7 64-bit. A few weeks ago, Firefox started to get the "not responding" error for about a minute or two, after which it went away and I could browse normally again. This happens every ten minutes or so.

I ran Firefox in safe mode for a while, but the same thing happened. It's totally random. Whether I'm using Flash or not, it happens just the same. Flash audio continues while Firefox freezes.

After uninstalling and wiping all the extra directories, I reinstalled. But the same thing happened again.

After this, I tried Palemoon. Virtually the same thing happened.

I've tried switching to Google Chrome, but it's sluggishly slow once I get 10+ tabs open. Opera is just too different for me and I'm not going to Internet Explorer or Safari.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be going on here?

Comment: In my experience, Firefox tended to freeze up when I've got javascript heavy tabs open or extensions running. I got fed up & Chrome mostly fixed the issue for me (it's more multi-core friendly), but if you're still having troubles on Chrome then that suggests to me you might have some misbehaving sites.. *what sites are you frequenting?* And when you say safe mode, *do you mean Windows safe mode, or Firefox safe mode?*

Comment: @Caspar: I meant Firefox safe mode. About JavaScript heavy sites, that never was an issue before on Firefox. For about 3 years I played a browser game that was pretty JavaScript-reliant, plus a bunch of greasemonkey scripts added. Never had freezes before. It's happened with just the Google search page open. Totally random.